# View command in Eclipse/statET

Tags: r, statet

R has a useful command ("View") that lets one see a table like a spreadsheet in a pop-up window. I used this command in the eclipse console while running statET and the spreadsheet popped up for a few milliseconds and then vanished.

To be specific, I have a matrix called "mat" and I typed

```
View(mat)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Object Browser window in Eclipse, you should see a list of the R objects you have in memory (under .GlobalEnv), as well as packages you've loaded (like reshape2 or plyr).

If you right-click on an R object in the .GlobalEnv list, you'll see an option to Open in Data Viewer. Clicking this option opens the data in a spreadsheet format in the Editor window, which is useful for getting a quick view of a small data set, or a subset of a larger one.

Comment: what if my data is not inside `.GlobalEnv` but inside some other function and I am inside that function during debugging session. Ideally it should show `Open in Data Viewer` option on right-click on data item inside the Variables window. However right click on data variable in Variables windows does not give such option. Also when I run `View(data_var)` in console it does not open StatEt Data Viewer, instead opens up R's data viewer which is very plain viewer without any features. Also want to know if there is any other way to open StatEt Data Viewer apart from right click under `.GlobalEnv`.